# Is there a way to force a trigger to run on an update statement with multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have had to make changes to a trigger and assumed that running an update query like the following would make the trigger execute for all the matched rows. But instead, it only updates the record that it finds.

```sql
UPDATE someTable SET someField = someField WHERE someField = 'something';
```

As a quick solution, I created the following query using a cursor to loop through the records and update each row. It works, and luckily I don't have a really large dataset so it doens't take too long, but it just doesn't seem like the best solution.

```sql
DECLARE @id INT;
DECLARE queryCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT id FROM someTable WHERE someField='something'

OPEN queryCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM queryCursor INTO @id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
 UPDATE someTable SET someField = someField WHERE id = @id
 FETCH NEXT FROM queryCursor INTO @id
END

CLOSE queryCursor
DEALLOCATE queryCursor
```

Is there a better way to get a trigger to execute on multiple rows in SQL Server?

**Edit: The code from trigger**

```sql
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE (LineNumber)
OR UPDATE(LineService)

Begin

DECLARE @CDL VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @LN VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @A  VARCHAR(25)

SELECT @CDL = CommonDataLink FROM INSERTED
SELECT @A = LineService FROM INSERTED

SET @LN = @CDL + @A

UPDATE CommonData SET ReportedLineNo = @LN WHERE CommonDataLink = @CDL

End
```

Comment: yes fix the trigger not the calling code! We need the trigger code to help you fix it, but triggers work on sets of data not one record ata time, If you wrote your trigger where you set a value from inserted or deleted to a scalar variable it is almost certainly incorrect and needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make use of the special table `INSERTED` for what you want:

**UPDATED CODE**

```
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE (LineNumber)
OR UPDATE(LineService)

Begin

DECLARE @CDL VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @LN VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @A  VARCHAR(25)

SELECT @CDL = CommonDataLink FROM INSERTED
SELECT @A = LineService FROM INSERTED

SET @LN = @CDL + @A

UPDATE A
SET ReportedLineNo = B.LineService + B.CommonDataLink
FROM CommonData A
INNER JOIN INSERTED B
ON A.CommonDataLink = B.CommonDataLink 


End
```

Comment: That's what I have in the trigger, but the trigger isn't being executed for each row when I run an update statement that effects multiple rows.

Comment: @xecaps12 - Then show us your trigger and the effect that you want. When a transaction that modifies or insert multiple rows on a table, the triggers gets executed once, with all the rows affected available on those special tables

Comment: I added the trigger to the question. When adding it I noticed the data type of the declared variable used to get the value doesn't match. I'm going to change it and see if it works.

Comment: @xecaps12 - Well, your trigger is assigning just one row to a variable, you can't assign multiple values on a variable that is not a table; so of course its only updating one result, you need to do a `JOIN` with the table `INSERTED`, as I have on my answer (updated with the code of your trigger)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I was doing some other things with the variables, but I think I can update the trigger to make it work. Of course it makes me realize I have several triggers that aren't working the way I originally assume. It explains so much.